# Unity3D Android file browser

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

does anyone know how would I create a file browser in Unity for an android OS? I don't actually know where to even start, even after I did a lot of search on it.

What I want, is for the user to be able to go through his folders on the phone or the SD card and he should be able to choose a text file, I would then save the text from the file into a string in my app and continue from there.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file navigation is as simple as using the .net 2.0 file browsing functions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

However you will have a lot of headaches trying to get Unity to play ball with Android's Intent broadcasters/receivers and will require a lot of fiddling with Java to launch the other Activity.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: I found Android Studio and decided to try it. It looks pretty cool and intuitive, the bad thing is that I can't find any kind of documentation on how to work with it together with Unity.
I found this [file browser](https://github.com/mburman/Android-File-Explore) which I can easily import into Android Studio and it works perfectly, exactly what I need.
Now I thought I would just need to import my project in here and somehow link these together.
The problem is, I exported my app as an Android Studio Project from Unity, imported it in Android Studio, but what to do next is a mystery to me :(

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into this: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ImprovedFileBrowser and its [relevant forum post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/84601-File-Browser). You might need to modify the script to work on Android, but it should be a good start.